# Как сравнить данные из Excel файла с таблицей когда БД в режиме Read Only?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Имеется БД в режиме только на чтение. В ней есть таблица с гигантским количеством записей (>3млрд.), и есть файл Excel с ~15000 строк с одним столбцом.

Как можно эффективно реализовать выгрузку записей, соответствующих строкам в Excel файле, когда БД в режиме **Read Only**?

Как я понял, даже создание временных таблиц не поможет, т.к. `CREATE` не сработает.

Comment: Сформировать CTE с этими 15000 значениями...

Comment: как извращенный вариант, сгенерировать запрос с запросом ваших 15 тысяч строк и выгрузить его результат. Но надо помнить, что в блоке in должно быть не больше 1000 значений, по этом вам придется использовать несколько таких блоков. Ну или как сказали выше, сделать with и с ним соедиянть

Comment: По поводу _read only_: если вам _действительно_ нужна запись в БД для какой-то цели, поговорите с руководством и админами СУБД: вам дадут строго ограниченный доступ на запись.

Comment: здесь многое будет зависеть от деталей и мелочей... Какова структура таблицы? Она, надеюсь, секционирована (`partitioned`)? Какие индексы существуют у таблицы для данного столбца? И т.д.

Comment: Создать новую БД. Залить данные из Excel. Сделать линк на read only БД. Сделать JOIN через линк, либо выгружать через него данные постепенно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В версии 18c появилась возможность объявлять внешние таблицы как часть SQL запроса (*inline*), то есть не создавaя их как постоянные обьекты в БД.

Для примера взял подготовку тестовой таблицы и данных [из соседнего ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1140238).

Сам запрос:

```
with ex as ( 
    select id 
    from external ((id number) 
        type oracle_loader default directory extfiles
        access parameters (records delimited by newline)
        location ('listid.dat')
    )
)
select t1.id, t1.memo, count (1) over () total  
from t1 join ex on t1.id = ex.id
order by 1 fetch first 3 rows only
/
        ID MEMO                  TOTAL
---------- ---------------- ----------
    100001 memo 100001           15000
    100002 memo 100002           15000
    100003 memo 100003           15000
```

Answer (score 3):

Простое решение - читать файл во временную таблицу в памяти и сравнивать с ней.

Сохранить Excel как текст, это просто, поэтому создал сразу текстовый файл:

```sh
$ seq 100001 115000 >/tmp/extfiles/listid.dat
```

Подготовка тестовой таблицы. Затем, БД переведенa в режим *Read Only*:

```sql
create table t1 (id number primary key, memo varchar2 (16));
insert into t1 
    select level, 'memo '||level from dual connect by level<=10e5;

SQL> show pdbs
    CON_ID CON_NAME                       OPEN MODE  RESTRICTED
---------- ------------------------------ ---------- ----------
         3 PDB1                           READ ONLY  NO
```

Выполнить анонимный блок и получить результат, и всё:

```
set autoprint on serveroutput on 
var rc refcursor
declare
    f utl_file.file_type;
    buff varchar2 (1024);
    idarr sys.odciNumberList := sys.odciNumberList (); 
begin 
    f := utl_file.fopen ('EXTFILES', 'listid.dat', 'r');
    begin loop
        utl_file.get_line (f, buff);
        idarr.extend;
        idarr(idarr.count) := to_number (buff);
    end loop; 
    exception when no_data_found then null;
    end; 
    utl_file.fclose(f); 
    dbms_output.put_line ('Lines read='||idarr.count);
    open :rc for 
        select t1.*, count (1) over () total  
        from t1 
        where exists (select 1 from table (idarr) t2 where t2.column_value=t1.id)
        fetch first 3 rows only;
end;
/
Elapsed: 00:00:00.132
Lines read=15000

        ID MEMO                  TOTAL
---------- ---------------- ----------
    100001 memo 100001           15000
    100002 memo 100002           15000
    100003 memo 100003           15000
```